# Why is my query failing with SQLCODE = -420?

Tags: sql, db2, sqlcode

Can I get some help with this? I'll copy the code as well as the error. I looked up the error code

> (DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, SQLERRMC=BOOLEAN)

but I'm not understanding what doesn't meet the requirements of the function? I'm just trying to pull these tables, rename *ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION* when it meets certain requirements, and then filter out the ones that don't meet the requirements. I also want to group by DESCRIPTION but I'd like to get this portion working first.

```
SELECT
    ACH_ORIGINATION.COMPANY_SERIAL,
    ACH_ORIGINATION.NAME,
    ACH_ORIGINATION.AMOUNT,
    ACH_ORIGINATION.NEXT_POSTING_DATE,
    CASE ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%J & J%' THEN 'J & J Electric'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DeCleene%' THEN 'DeCleene'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arab%' THEN 'Arab'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Clifford%' THEN 'Clifford Signs'
        ELSE 'Nothing'
    END AS DESCRIPTION
FROM
    CORE.ACH_ORIGINATION AS ACH_ORIGINATION
WHERE
    ACH_ORIGINATION.NEXT_POSTING_DATE IS NOT NULL AND
    DESCRIPTION <> 'Nothing'
```

**Error:**

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : ACH32Origination32Report_TableDataset_1579792666108_134237
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:466)
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$18(ReportControler.java:441)
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$4.run(ReportControler.java:333)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
>   Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : ACH32Origination32Report_TableDataset_1579792666108_134237
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:809)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTableSubreport.prepareSubreport(FillTableSubreport.java:156)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.prepare(FillTable.java:400)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:151)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:332)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:384)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:358)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummaryNoLastFooterSamePage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1102)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1065)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:329)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:159)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : ACH32Origination32Report_TableDataset_1579792666108_134237
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:240)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1114)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:691)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1314)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:931)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:873)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:665)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:203)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, SQLERRMC=BOOLEAN, DRIVER=4.13.127
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:669)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:60)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:127)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bo.b(bo.java:4101)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bo.a(bo.java:4083)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:835)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.n(cb.java:801)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.j(cb.java:253)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.d(cb.java:55)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.c(q.java:44)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.j(sb.java:147)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.no.kb(no.java:2112)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.b(oo.java:4407)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.fc(oo.java:743)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.executeQuery(oo.java:713)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:233)
>       ... 11 more

Comment: You are mixing syntaxes, either `case colum when value` or `case when condition`

Comment: `case` expression syntax... Simply do `case when ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I understand where the error was now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments, fix the CASE expression like this:

```
CASE    WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%J & J%' THEN 'J & J Electric'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DeCleene%' THEN 'DeCleene'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arab%' THEN 'Arab'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Clifford%' THEN 'Clifford Signs'
        ELSE 'Nothing'
END AS DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Scratch my previous comment about them all being labeled as 'Nothing' - it seems to be working properly now, however, I am getting an error now that I'm trying to group by the DESCRIPTION. All I did was add GROUP BY DESCRIPTION after the WHERE clause and now I'm getting DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE= -119, SQLSTATE=42803, SQLERRMC=NEXT_POSTING_DATE, DRIVER=3.58.82.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's better to post a new question, if your original problem is resolved, and now you have a new problem...
Multiple problems with `GROUP BY`. You may run the query below to play with expressions.

1) You must use some aggregate function on a column which is not presented in the `GROUP BY` list, but used in the `SELECT` list. If you uncomment the 1-st line commented out, and comment out the next line (with `MAX` function), you get SQLCODE=-119.

2) Unanticipated / wrong expression in the `GROUP BY` clause.
You should use the same `case` expression in the `group by` clause, and not the original `DESCRIPTION` column. If you uncomment commented out `--DESCRIPTION` line and comment out the `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` list, you may "suddenly" realize, that you get 2 groups with the same value in the `DESCRIPTION` column. This is because of you group by the original value in `DESCRIPTION` first and process the group value in the `CASE` expression afterwards.

```
SELECT
    --ACH_ORIGINATION.NEXT_POSTING_DATE,
    MAX(ACH_ORIGINATION.NEXT_POSTING_DATE) AS NEXT_POSTING_DATE,
    CASE 
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%J & J%' THEN 'J & J Electric'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DeCleene%' THEN 'DeCleene'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arab%' THEN 'Arab'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Clifford%' THEN 'Clifford Signs'
        ELSE 'Nothing'
    END AS DESCRIPTION
, COUNT(1) CNT    
FROM 
(
VALUES 
  (CURRENT DATE - 1, 'Arab1') 
, (CURRENT DATE - 2, 'Arab2')  
) ACH_ORIGINATION (NEXT_POSTING_DATE, DESCRIPTION)
WHERE
    ACH_ORIGINATION.NEXT_POSTING_DATE IS NOT NULL AND
    DESCRIPTION <> 'Nothing'
GROUP BY 
--DESCRIPTION
    CASE 
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%J & J%' THEN 'J & J Electric'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%DeCleene%' THEN 'DeCleene'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arab%' THEN 'Arab'
        WHEN ACH_ORIGINATION.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Clifford%' THEN 'Clifford Signs'
        ELSE 'Nothing'
    END
;
```